# What's the difference between undirected graph and unweighted graph? Are they the same thing?

Tags: graph, undirected-graph

What's the difference between undirected graph and unweighted graph? Are they the same thing? Just want to be 100% sure.

I'm new to all this. Please don't lock I just need help and would like to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undirected graph means that his edges do not have any orientation, you can traverse it in both ways. Unweighted graph means that his edges are assumed to be the  same length (or that the length does not matter).